# Entity Framework not support expression trees

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, expression-trees

I try sort my queryable collection with custom expression:

```
.Lambda #Lambda1<System.Func`2[MyProject.Client,System.Object]>(MyProject.Client $var1)
{
    .Block() {
        .If ($var1.Legal == null) {
            .Return #Label1 { (System.Object)($var1.Person).Email }
        } .Else {
            .Return #Label1 { (System.Object)($var1.Legal).Email }
        };
        .Label
            .Constant<System.Object>(System.Object)
        .LabelTarget #Label1:
    }
}
```

However, when attempting cast my collection to list application throws exception:

```
An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unknown LINQ expression of type 'Block'.
```

**UPD to Stilgar**

I use conditional expression. My sort extension:

```
public static IOrderedQueryable<TSource> SortMultipleField<TSource>(this IQueryable<TSource> source, string propNames, bool ascending)
{
    var type = typeof(TSource);
    var param = Expression.Parameter(type);

    var sortFields = propNames.Split(',');

    Expression firstParent = param;
    var firstFieldPath = sortFields[0].Split('.');
    foreach (var item in firstFieldPath)
        firstParent = Expression.Property(firstParent, item);
    firstParent = Expression.Convert(firstParent, typeof(object));

    Expression secondParent = param;
    foreach (var item in sortFields[1].Split('.'))
        secondParent = Expression.Property(secondParent, item);
    secondParent = Expression.Convert(secondParent, typeof(object));

    var check = Expression.Property(param, firstFieldPath[0]);
    var checkNullExpression = Expression.Equal(check, Expression.Constant(null, check.Type));
    var returnTarget = Expression.Label(typeof(object));

    var block = Expression.Block(
        Expression.IfThenElse(
            checkNullExpression,
            Expression.Return(returnTarget, secondParent),
            Expression.Return(returnTarget, firstParent)),
        Expression.Label(returnTarget, Expression.Constant(new object())));

    var sortExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(block, param);

    if (ascending)
        return source.OrderBy(sortExpression);

    return source.OrderByDescending(sortExpression);
}
```

Comment: I do not see any use of conditional expression. Am I missing something?

Comment: Expression IfThenElse returns conditional expression

Comment: Oh I see. But you must remove the Block anyway. This would probably require reworking your code since it uses return statements which would be invalid in a pure expression (as opposed to statement). Can you show the C# code this expression tree is supposed to represent just to be sure we are on the same page

Comment: Hmmm, when i used pure conditional expression (without Block), orderBy throws exception "Void cannot be cast to Object". I must return result. How I can do it without Block?

Comment: I don't think the Block actually helps you. I mean the code with the block was raising an error before you hit that error. Can you provide the C# code you are trying to achieve. I think what you want to do would be easier using the ThenBy method.

Comment: Simple linq sample:
myQuery.OrderBy(x => x.Legal == null ? x.Person.Email : x.Legal.Email)

My code above works for iqueryable collection without DB provider.

ThenBy can not help to me. It's consistently sorting. It is not suitable in my situation.

Comment: So how about this Expression.IfThenElse(checkNullExpression, secondParent, firstParent)

Comment: Code: Expression.Lambda<Func<TSource, object>>(Expression.IfThenElse(checkNullExpression, secondParent,firstParent), param) throws exception:  "Expression of type 'System.Void' cannot be used for return type 'System.Object'"

Comment: Ditch the IfThenElse & Block, you want to use ConditionalExpression as indicated by Stilgar, and see what happens.

Comment: @christo can you check which of the expressions has type void? Maybe if you use the overload that takes a Type as last argument you can specify the type and it will work?

Answer (score 4):

I believe Entity Framework does not support statement lambdas only expressions. You may have more luck if you can somehow convert the if statement into a [conditional expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.conditionalexpression(v=vs.110).aspx).

It seems that you are trying to sort on multiple properties. I think this would be easier to do using the ThenBy method.

Answer (score -3):

Yeah. How do you think entity framework is gong to translate your custom expression into - ah - SQL?

Hint: it can not. SImple like that. it tells you that.

I suggest you scrap the sort, get EF return whatever you ask for as IEnumerable, THEN sort the result of that (which then happens not in SQL but using LINQ for Objects because EF ends at the IEnumerable). This should allow the sort to happen in memory where the .NET runtime can make sense out of your custom expression.

Comment: downvote because: 1) ofcourse EF can translate your "custom expressions" into SQL, that's the whole point of EF. (Stilgar is right; not all lambdas will be "convertable") 2) pulling huge data to client-side just to sort it is very bad advice.

Comment: BTW how do we know the expression is related to sorting?

Comment: @Stilgar: it seems to say in the first sentence: "I try sort my queryable collection with custom expression:"

Comment: Oh I see. I somehow missed that.

Comment: @TomTom: Not sure what point you're trying to make here. He's trying to build "myQuery.OrderBy(x => x.Legal == null ? x.Person.Email : x.Legal.Email)" dynamically, and that is supported by EF. It's a simple SQL that has orderby backed up by CASE/WHEN. About sorting: Sure. Though, you're assuming that OrderBy() is not followed by Take(). I can't really download 100k records to my client's machine just to sort them and take ~50 ones which I need for now.